# How to debug C++ program with much data to be checked?

Tags: c++, debugging, io, printf

Say I have a C++ program with 100 functions, and each function with 100 local variables, and each of them is an array, maybe 1D, maybe 2D, maybe 3D, maybe dynamically allocated. 
Now I'm debugging the program and I have to check if all the variables are correct. Now I simply `fprintf()` them to their own files, and then check the data in the files. But I have to write many many `fprintf()` statements and `fopen(), fclose()` statements in the program, which is quite ugly.

Are there any better way or tool that can simplify and possibly automate this stuff?

Comment: This question is way to broad to answer, please post code, output and expected output.

Comment: If you have a program like what you describe, you *don't'* debug it. You throw it away and go back to the drawing board and start all over with a new and improved design. A program like that is basically unmaintainable.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with specific code? Or is it a purely theoretical question?

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude Kudos to throwing it away

Comment: There is a tool called a *debugger* it will show you what all the variables contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use debugger for that, but it'll require to check everything on your own.
If you want to check everything automatically, just write unit tests and run them.

Answer (score 0):

> and each function with 100 local variable

There's your problem.  Cut that so that each function is 100 lines (even then it's still too much!) and you'll have a fighting chance

Answer (score 0):

Create a global log file and open/close it once.
Debug print is a powerful tool, but I suppose you'll need also a tool (write yourself) to compare the result files.

Answer (score 0):

At first, as @UKMonkey already said your function shouldn't have 100 local variables. The best practice is to have functions with **maximum 25 lines and maximum 80 characters in each line**. That will make easier for you to debug and for others to understand your code.

Furthermore, if you use linux or other unix-like (unix based) systems, you can use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) for debugging. Just compile your app giving -g flag to gcc/g++ and run it using GDB.

```
$ g++ -g example.cpp -o example.out
$ gdb ./example.out
```

there you can add breakpoints and print values of your variables. Read GDB [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) for more details